# Using OutputRaw in Java Tapestry

Tags: java, html, output, tapestry

I have a web application running Java Tapestry, with a lot of user-inputted content. The only formatting that users may input is linebreaks.

I call a text string from a database, and output it into a template. The string contains line breaks as /r, which I replace with < br >. However, these are filtered on output, so the text looks like b<br>text text b<br> text. I think I can use outputRaw or writeRaw to fix this, but I can't find any info for how to add outputRaw or writeRaw to a Tapestry class or template.

The class is:

```
 public String getText() {
    KMedium textmedium = getTextmedium();
    return (textmedium == null || textmedium.getTextcontent() == null) ? "" : textmedium.getTextcontent().replaceAll("\r", "<br>");
    }
```

The tml is:

```
<p class="categorytext" id="${currentCategory.id}">
${getText()}
</p>
```

Where would I add the raw output handling to have my line breaks display properly?

Answer (score 4):

To answer my own question, this is how to output the results of $getText() as raw html:

Change the tml from this:

```
<p class="categorytext" id="${currentCategory.id}">
${getText()}
</p>
```

To this:

```
<p class="categorytext" id="${currentCategory.id}">
<t:outputraw value="${getText()}"/>
</p>
```

Comment: Note that ```<t:outputraw value="${getText()}" />``` is better written as ```<t:outputraw value="text" />```

Answer (score 3):

Note that this is quite dangerous as you are likely opening your site to an [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attack. You may need to use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer) or similar to sanitize the input.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative might be:

```
<p class="categorytext" id="${currentCategory.id}">
   <t:loop source="textLines" value="singleLine">
    ${singleLine}  <br/>
   </t:loop>
 </p>
```

This assumes a a `getTextLines()` method that returns a List or array of Strings; it could use the same logic as your `getText()` but split the result on CRs.  This would do a better job when the text lines contain unsafe characters such as `&` or `<`.  With a little more work, you could add the `<br>` only between lines (not after each line) ... and this feels like it might be a nice component as well.